# Automatically restart a systemd service when a file is modified on disk

Tags: systemd

I have a service, basically a Nomad Client. A minimal version of it looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Nomad Client
Documentation=https://nomadproject.io/docs/
After=network-online.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/nomad agent -config /etc/myapp/myconfig.json

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This service starts a nomad process with a specific config available at `/etc/myapp/myconfig.json`.

The application I am working with is build around this nomad client and during the life cycle of the application the config file can change at any point of time.

I want to restart the service whenever `/etc/myapp/myconfig.json` changes on disk.

Answer (score 9):

You want to create a [path unit](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.path.html).

For the purpose of this answer, I'm going to assume your service unit is called `nomad.service`.

First, create a `nomad-restart.service` `oneshot` service that will
restart your `nomad` service. Create
/etc/systemd/system/nomad-restart.service with the following content:

```
[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/systemctl restart nomad.service
```

Next, we need a `.path` unit to activate a service when a specified
file is modified. Create `/etc/systemd/system/nomad-restart.path` with
the following content:

```
[Path]
PathChanged=/etc/myapp/myconfig.json

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Start and enable the path unit:

```
systemctl enable --now nomad-restart.path
```

Now whenever the specified path is changed, your service will restart.
The `nomad-restart.path` unit will trigger when the specified file is
modified. This will cause it to activate (aka "start") the
`nomad-restart.service` until, which will call `systemctl restart nomad.service` and then exit.

Comment: Hi @Iarsks, I am also working on similar use case. Should we need to execute `systemctl enable --now *.path` manually? Or is it enough to reboot the device?  Because I read that `.path` files are started when the system starts. Right?

Comment: If you want a systemd unit to start when the system boots, you need to `systemctl enable` it. If you want the unit to start without rebooting the system, you need to either `systemctl start` it or use the `--now` flag on `systemctl enable`.

Comment: @Iarsks, thanks for quick response. So, without enabling it the `.path` unit file won't be executed even after reboot. And only solution would be to manually enable it first.

Comment: Hi @larsks, I am wondering if this is case-sensitive or not `Type=OneShot` should it be `oneshot`?

Comment: @Preeti Good catch! You are correct. I've corrected it in the answer.